# What is causing this repeated kernel panic?

Tags: snow-leopard, kernel-panic

```
Thu May 10 14:29:35 2012
panic(cpu 1 caller 0x2abf6a): Kernel trap at 0x01549b37, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x8001003b, CR2: 0x000003dc, CR3: 0x00100000, CR4: 0x00000660
EAX: 0x092c3f40, EBX: 0x08c40000, ECX: 0x00000090, EDX: 0x0bb32100
CR2: 0x000003dc, EBP: 0x5d80be48, ESI: 0x00000000, EDI: 0x00000002
EFL: 0x00010246, EIP: 0x01549b37, CS:  0x00000008, DS:  0x0a1f0010
Error code: 0x00000000

Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address (4 potential args on stack)
0x5d80bc28 : 0x21b837 (0x5dd7fc 0x5d80bc5c 0x223ce1 0x0) 
0x5d80bc78 : 0x2abf6a (0x59e3d0 0x1549b37 0xe 0x59e59a) 
0x5d80bd58 : 0x2a1a78 (0x5d80bd70 0x0 0x5d80be48 0x1549b37) 
0x5d80bd68 : 0x1549b37 (0xe 0x48 0x5d800010 0x550010) 
0x5d80be48 : 0x93df3b (0x8c40000 0x92c3400 0x2 0x0) 
0x5d80bed8 : 0x553ec7 (0x91a4700 0x92c4380 0x1 0x2275c6) 
0x5d80bf28 : 0x552ea6 (0x92c4380 0x0 0x0 0x0) 
0x5d80bf88 : 0x552eea (0x92c41c0 0x9143980 0xffe008a0 0x7fff) 
0x5d80bfc8 : 0x2a179c (0x92c41c0 0x0 0x10 0xc07c5a4) 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace (with dependencies):
         com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor(3.0.1d2)@0x1548000->0x154efff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleSMC(3.1.0d5)@0x939000
         com.apple.driver.AppleSMC(3.1.0d5)@0x939000->0x942fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.3.0)@0x935000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
10K549

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 10.8.0: Tue Jun  7 16:33:36 PDT 2011; root:xnu-1504.15.3~1/RELEASE_I386
System model name: MacBookPro4,1 (Mac-F42C89C8)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 290739192920044
unloaded kexts:
com.apple.driver.AirPortBrcm43xx    423.91.27 (addr 0xf01000, size 0x1900544) - last unloaded 172712553560
loaded kexts:
com.nvidia.CUDA 1.1.0
com.cisco.nke.ipsec 2.0.1
com.paragon-software.filesystems.ntfs   95
com.Cycling74.driver.Soundflower    1.5.2
com.markspace.driver.Android.RNDIS  1.2
com.rim.driver.BlackBerryUSBDriverInt   0.0.67
com.apple.filesystems.smbfs 1.6.7 - last loaded 81577376770601
com.apple.driver.AppleHWSensor  1.9.3d0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    2.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   2.0.5f14
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.57
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AudioIPCDriver 1.1.6
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.0.46
com.apple.kext.AppleSMCLMU  1.5.2d10
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.5.7
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.0.20
com.apple.driver.SMCMotionSensor    3.0.1d2
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    4.7.0a1
com.apple.GeForce   6.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPenrynProfile    17.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons  201.6
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard 201.6
com.apple.driver.AppleIRController  303.8
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  2.6.8
com.apple.BootCache 31.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  1.6.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    4.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelPIIXATA  2.5.1
com.apple.driver.AppleFWOHCI    4.7.3
com.apple.iokit.AppleYukon2 3.2.1b1
com.apple.driver.AirPortBrcm43224   428.42.4
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  2.1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBEHCI   4.2.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBUHCI   4.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  1.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   1.3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   160.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   1.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    1.7
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    1.3.6
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient 142.6.0
com.apple.security.sandbox  1
com.apple.security.quarantine   0
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   2.1.14
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement   142.6.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 2.0.5f14
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileReadCounterAction  17
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileTimestampAction    10
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileThreadInfoAction   14
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileRegisterStateAction    10
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileKEventAction   10
com.apple.driver.AppleProfileCallstackAction    20
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   74.2
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    2.4.5f3
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  10.0.3
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   1.8.3fc2
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.3
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.0.1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 4.7.0a1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 2.0.5f14
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 2.0.5f14
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireIP    2.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.0d5
com.apple.nvidia.nv50hal    6.3.6
com.apple.NVDAResman    6.3.6
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.2.1
com.apple.iokit.AppleProfileFamily  41.4
com.apple.driver.BroadcomUSBBluetoothHCIController  2.4.5f3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBBluetoothHCIController 2.4.5f3
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   2.4.5f3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch 207.7
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  4.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   4.2.4
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIMultimediaCommandsDevice  2.6.8
com.apple.iokit.IOBDStorageFamily   1.6
com.apple.iokit.IODVDStorageFamily  1.6
com.apple.iokit.IOCDStorageFamily   1.6.1
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 402.1
com.apple.iokit.IOATAPIProtocolTransport    2.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 4.2.4
com.apple.iokit.IOATAFamily 2.5.1
com.apple.iokit.IOFireWireFamily    4.2.6
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   320.1
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  1.10
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    1.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 1.6.6
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   2.6.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  3.9.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   2.6.8
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   2.6.8
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 4.2.4
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 289.1
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 1.6.3
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  1.3.6
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.6.5
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.3.0
```

It only seems to occur when I move the laptop quickly or if the computer gets bumped for some reason. I put a bigger HDD in the laptop, could that be the problem?

Comment: Does it happen when you start up in Safe Boot Mode? (Boot while holding the Shift key; it may take a while to start up)

Comment: Before even trying to attack the drivers, if you can reproduce the KP it would be worth running on a clean install of the OS from an external drive to rule out your current SW stack

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to [reset the Apple SMC](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964?viewlocale=en_US) on your Mac ?
It appears in the backtrace of the kernel panic, so it worth try it.

Moreover, the SMC manage the Sudden Motion Sensor (SMS) as said on the page :

> **Additional Information**
>
> The System Management Controller (SMC) is responsible for many low-level functions on Intel-based Macs.
> These functions include:
>
> - Responding to presses of the power button
> - Responding to display lid opening and closing on portable Macs
> - Battery management
> - Thermal management
> - **The SMS (Sudden Motion Sensor)**
> - Ambient light sensing
> - Keyboard backlighting
> - Status Indicator Light (SIL) management
> - Battery status indicator lights
> - Selecting an external (instead of internal) video source for some iMac displays

The SMS is involved when your move your Mac rapidly as you said.

Hope this helps !